# Where to search for more info if I don't have Internet?

Tags: linux, man

For example, I was reading `setuid` man page today. It says:

> If the effective UID of the caller is root, the real UID and saved set-user-ID are also set.

I don't know what `set-user-ID` is. How can I get more information about it if I don't have Internet connection?

One thing I can do is to open some books and search for it.

What are other places on my Linux system where I can search for more information?

Comment: Why is this CW?

Comment: @phunehehe: editing title again. I am looking for other places where I can search. Not only man pages.

Comment: do you just want random sources that may or may not be installed on a unix system? (e.g. perldoc, info, html doc, --help) I'm not really sure what you're looking for...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `apropos`

```
apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions
```

Try `apropos 'set user id'` for an example.

Comment: +1 for apropos. But its give me only manpages with that string :-( not much description.

Comment: @Hemant you're supposed to then open the man pages it gives you... It's basically a very simple local man page search engine

Answer (score 8):

apropos is also spelled 'man -k'

Answer (score 3):

Some applications (mostly those of GNU origin) come with '[info](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/)' pages.

These pages usually contain a more in-depth manual of the application, and lots of extra information which you can find very useful for learning. To see if the info documentation for an application is installed, just type `info xxx` (if the manual is not installed it will load the man page instead).

In Ubuntu at least, info pages are in a separate `foo-doc` package, where `foo` is the name of the application (ie. `gcc`, `make`, etc).

And yes, the browser is lame.